# logstash output s3 file name

Tags: amazon-s3, logstash

I would like to control the file extension name for the outputted files in s3 I do not see a documented option, I'm sure I'm just missing something.

```
output {
  s3 {
     region => "us-east-1"
    bucket => "my_bucket"
    size_file => 10000
    restore => true
    prefix => "my_folder/"
    codec => "json_lines"
      }
}
```

right now the files have a .txt extension I would like them to have a .json extension.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using using a leading slash in prefix, try the below code.

```
output {
  s3 {
     region => "us-east-1"
    bucket => "my_bucket"
    size_file => 10000
    restore => true
    prefix => "my_folder"
    codec => "json_lines"
      }
}
```

Comment: had no effect on the file extension